# string.length outputting wrong value?

Tags: javascript, angular

This code is in html template inside ngFor loop

```
{{ (user.text.length>1)? (user.text | slice:0:1)+'...':(user.text) }}
{{user.text.length}}
```

user is object which has text property example below.

```
 user {
    name: dslkdskld,
    text: [johnd dskjsd, mark kdsdlk, joe sldk, john sdkds]
   }
```

String.length in this case outputs 4. Does it assume everything prior to coma 1 character ?
I was hoping to get the character length of entire user.text

Comment: It's hard to say when the code has syntax errors, as the example code does. The answer guesses that you have an array because of the brackets, but without seeing where the actual quote marks are, it is just a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `user.text` is not `text` , its `array` here

Try to print `{{ user.text[0] }}` , that will clear your doubts

What you are expecting should look like this

```
user {
    name: "dslkdskld",
    text: "[johnd dskjsd, mark kdsdlk, joe sldk, john sdkds]" // <--- within quotes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript `Array` and `String` have a length property.

So,
this is Array with 4 elements:

`[johnd dskjsd, mark kdsdlk, joe sldk, john sdkds]`

And this `dslkdskld` it's a String with length 9

And you can choose which length you need in your example.